# Why does vertically centering a web page cut off on small monitors and mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, position, margin, css-position

Right now I have a website which has an overall height set at 750px. I have it vertically centered using the position absolute and negative margin method. It works great apart from one problem.

If I try use it on a lower-res monitor or mobile device it cuts the top of the page.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="content">
CONTENT IS HERE
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
position:absolute;
top:50%;
height:750px;
margin-top:-375px; /* Half of 750px */
}
```

I tried using overflow:scroll; on the body tag but I understand that it doesn't work, I didn't expect it to.  I am totally stumped! Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Introducing........ @media-queries! http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite it with a [mediaquery](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml) on small screens:

```
.content {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    height:750px;
    margin-top:-375px;
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 750px){
    .content {
        top:0;
        margin-top:0;
    }
}
```

Actually, this is a graceful degradation method, but if you're designing for mobile you probably want to approach in a [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) way. In that case, it becomes:

```
.content {
    height:750px;
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 751px){
    .content {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        margin-top:-375px;
    }
}
```

---

Speaking about compatibility, the `only` keyword after `@media` prevent older browsers from rendering the rules contained.

To reach (almost) full compatibility, you can use this very useful plugin: [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: Spot on! thank you so much.  Just a quick question. Is this compatiable with older browsers?

Comment: No it's not, check compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries). That's why i added the `only` keyword after `@media`, so old browsers won't render it. I'll edit my answer to add some polyfills.

Answer (score 0):

As far as scrolling goes,

```
overflow:auto;
```

is probably what you want as that will cause the scroll bars to appear.

This overall problem you are having is why sizing is almost always done relatively. Either relative with percentages, or relative with javascript to determine the clients viewable area.

Also note that,

```
.class {
```

does not match the definition you have `class="content"`. This is a logical error and should be replaced with

```
.content {
```

Comment: It won't work with auto either.  Whenever you use a negative value for a margin, it can't be scrolled if it cuts the edge of the window.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like

```
margin-top:-25%;
```

So that it will be the same at any browser window height

And the same for the height, use a combination of percentages, not pixels.

Comment: Sorry, I posted my edit on your answer briefly. I removed it.

Comment: If 25% is different from 375px this won't center the div vertically on desktop screens. His method is right.

Comment: His method is another method of vertically aligning the div to the page, but it doesn't solve my problem here

Comment: @PeterStuart i meant _your_ method is right, and his answer is wrong

Comment: My apolgies @GionaF  Thanks again for the answer. Your such a life saver lol!